# Want to execute my js script just after npm run build

Tags: javascript, vue.js, npm, build

everyone . i want to execute my JavaScript file just after npm run build get successful message . currently looking for vue js code base. or is there any way i can log and can create a file in my code repo of that  'run build get successful' message

Answer (score 0):

In your package.json :

```
"scripts": {
    "build": "run-script build && echo 'run build get successful'",
  },
```